# allow specific files and block the rest

Tags: iis, request-filtering

i tryied to allow specific files in iis 10

> MED.exe StartMed.exe

and block exe extention with request filtering
[*request filtering*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Jnb.png)

but i got this error
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oQOs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use request filtering for such scenarios.

To block certain URL patterns, please use [URL Rewrite module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to write rules.

Instead of redirecting/rewriting, the rules can perform actions such as aborting connections or returning error codes preferred by you.

Comment: Can you share me example how can i creating such role?